# const char * constexpr evaluated at compile time and at run time

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

In the following example, I use `static_assert` to verify that `foo` is determined at compile time. The `static_assert` passes and I've checked with an incorrect condition that it's actually active. This implies that `foo` is known at compile time. But if I step through the code with a debugger, I see that `skip_first_word` is also executed at run time.

```
// Skip the first word in p_str
constexpr const char * skip_first_word(const char * p_str) {
    return (*p_str == '\0') ? p_str : 
        (*p_str == ' ') ? p_str + 1 : 
        skip_first_word(p_str + 1);
}

// constexpr to calculate the length of a string
constexpr size_t str_len(const char * p_str) {
    return (*p_str == '\0') ? 0 : str_len(p_str + 1) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto foo = skip_first_word("Hello, World!");
    constexpr auto foo_size = str_len(foo);
    static_assert(foo_size == 6, "Wrong size");

    // This assert successfully fails
    // static_assert(foo_size == 7, "Wrong size");

    // Prevent optimizations
    for(auto ptr = foo; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr) {
        volatile auto sink = ptr;
    }
    volatile auto sink = &foo_size;

    return 0;
}
```

What's going on here? Why can't the `foo` that was calculated at compile-time be used at runtime?

Edit: This behavior is observed with Visual Studio 2015

Comment: You've used the same optimization level in both cases, right?

Comment: @n.caillou Yes, I've run both cases with and without optimizations.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: updated my answer to cover VS2015 behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/gPJld5) shows that your code is completely optimized out with both **gcc 7** and **clang 3.9**, using the `-std=c++11 -O1` flags.

Uncommenting the `volatile` operations will obviously generate assembly instructions, but no instructions are generated for `skip_first_word` or `str_len`.

---

You're correct regarding Visual Studio: using [CL 19 on gcc.beta.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/nq8Of0) shows that assembly is being generated for:

```
constexpr auto foo = skip_first_word("Hello, World!");
constexpr auto foo_size = str_len(foo);
```

**This seems like a compiler implementation defect, as `constexpr` variables  should and could be completely computed at compile-time.** Additionally, the variables are being used inside a `static_assert`, which is **guaranteed to be evaluated at compile-time**. This seems to suggest that the compiler is unnecessarily generating assembly for `skip_first_word` and `str_len`, even though they are never used in a run-time context.

Manually inlining the code as follows...

```
static_assert(str_len(skip_first_word("Hello, World!")) == 6, "Wrong size");
static_assert(str_len(skip_first_word("Hello, World!")) != 7, "Wrong size");
```

[...produces no extra assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/erls71).